# Determining unknown scalar using area relationship

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, area, planar-graphs

I have the following equations and trying to determine the value of $a$

$g(x) = ax$

$f(x) = -2(x-3)(x^2+1)$

I am trying to identify the unknown value of a > 0 such that the following holds: the region that is bounded by the y-axis, the plot of f(x), and the plot of the linear function g(x) = ax, has area exactly 6.

I know for a start that I need to start with calculating the intersection of the two graphs $a$ but i do not know how to set it up and proceed to solve the question.

[image]

this is a rough sketch of f(x) and y=x

But I can not find the answer as it is quite challenging.

Comment: so did you set up the integral yet?

Comment: I am not sure how to set up to find the intersection so not yet.

Comment: At the point of intersection, $g(x)=f(x)$.